# Replacing specific values within a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am running the following code in jupyter notebook which checks strings of text within `nametest_df['text']` and returns Persons names. I managed to get this working and would like to push these names to the respective fields within the `nametest_df['name']` where currently all values are `NaN`.

I tried the `Series.replace()` method however all entries within the 'name' column are all showing the same name.

Any clue how I can do this efficiently?

```
for word in nametest_df['text']:

    for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(word):
        tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(sent)
        tags = st.tag(tokens)

        for tag in tags:
            if tag[1]=='PERSON':
                name = tag[0]
                print(name)

    nametest_df.name = nametest_df.name.replace({"NaN": name})
```

Sample nametest_df

```
      **text**                    **name**
0   His name is John                NaN
1   I went to the beach             NaN
2   My friend is called Fred        NaN
```

Expected output

```
      **text**                    **name**
0   His name is John                John                
1   I went to the beach             NaN
2   My friend is called Fred        Fred
```

Comment: post a sample df and expected df

Answer (score 1):

Don't try and fill series values one by one. This is inefficient prone to error. A better idea is to create a **list** of names and assign directly.

```
L = []
for word in nametest_df['text']:
    for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(word):
        tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(sent)
        tags = st.tag(tokens)
        for tag in tags:
            if tag[1]=='PERSON':
                L.append(tag[0])

nametest_df.loc[nametest_df['name'].isnull(), 'name'] = L
```

Comment: This is giving the following error: ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

I suspect this is happening due to some text fields not containing a name. How can I keep the NaN values for fields where the algorithm doesn't pick up a name?

Comment: @MarkTrapani, See update, you can use `loc` to mask for null values. You have to ensure that the number of values produced by your logic equals the number of null values. Otherwise, you have to fix your `for` loop.

Comment: Which for loop should be changed to push a NaN value to the name column where no names are found?

Comment: @MarkTrapani, Not sure, I have no idea about the `ntlk` library, you should be able to work this out with your data by using `print`.